# In bash, how do I get the index of the last element of an array without a loop

Tags: bash, array

In bash, is it possible to get the index of the last element of an array (that might be sparse) without looping through the entire array like so:

```
a=( e0 e1 ... )
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt $(( ${#a[@]} - 1 )) ]
do
  let 'i=i+1'
done
echo "$i"
```

Since at least bash v 4.2, I can get the *value* of the last element in an array using

```
e="${array[-1]}"
```

but that will not get me the *positive* index since other elements may have the same value.

Comment: The loop in question seems pointless. You might as well have written `i=$((${#a[@]}-1))`.

Comment: @muru Since arrays might be sparse `$(( ${#a[@]} - 1 ))` will give the number of elements in the array. That may or *may not* be the same as the index of the last element.

Comment: That may be, but *the loop you show in the question* is pointless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case of an array which is not sparse, last index is number of elements - 1:

```
i=$(( ${#a[@]} - 1 ))
```

To include the case of a sparse array, you can create the array of indexes and get the last one:

```
a=( [0]=a [1]=b [9]=c )

indexes=( "${!a[@]}" )
i="${indexes[-1]}"

echo "$i"
9
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
lst=( [0]=1 [1]=2 [9]=3 )
echo ${lst[@]@A}           # show elements and indexes
echo ${lst[-1]}            # last  element
echo ${!lst[@]}            # list of indexes
: ${!lst[@]} ; echo $_     # last index
```